# How can I reduce Execution time of Python code

Tags: python-3.x

In this this code I'm calculating difference between squares of `n` numbers and the square of the sum of `n` numbers.

Example : `n=3, (1+2+3)^2 -(1^2+2^2+3^2) =22`

```
def sum_square_diff(num):
    sum1=0
    sum2=0
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        sum1 +=i**2
        sum2 +=i
    sum2=sum2**2
    diff=sum2-sum1
    return diff

if __name__=="__main__":
    n=int(input())
    for i in range(n):
        num=int(input())
        result=sum_square_diff(num)
        print(result)
```

This code is correct but it takes too much time to complete execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first place, the formula that you want to compute has a **closed-form representation**. There is no need for any loops:

```
n*n*(n+1)*(n+1)/4 - n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6
```

But if you insist, you can get >3x speedup by using numpy instead of raw Python:

```
def sum_square_diff1(num): 
    x = np.arange(1,num+1) 
    return x.sum()**2-(x**2).sum() 

In [7]: %timeit sum_square_diff(100)                                            
19.6 µs ± 435 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit sum_square_diff1(100)                                           
5.61 µs ± 26.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```